# Number of stereoisomers of a polyene

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

Find the number of stereoisomers of the following compound:

[image: 4-(buta-1,3-dien-1-yl)-1,2-dimethyl-5-(penta-1,2,3-trien-1-yl)cyclohex-1-ene]

I think the answer is 16:

- The double bond in the ring cannot show geometrical isomerism.
- The first double bond on the top substituent can show *cis-trans* isomerism and the one on the end will not show *cis-trans* isomerism because of two same groups on one carbon.
- The substituent on the bottom that is: $\ce{-CH=C=C=CHMe}$ can also show *cis-trans* isomerism.
- Then, there are two chiral centres and the number of optical isomers is $2^2=4$. The total number of stereoisomers is 16.

But the answer given is 4. Am I correct or not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words so I've redrawn your compound and have numbered the areas to be considered.

[image]

- Double bond "1" is not capable of displaying *cis-trans*
  stereoisomers since there are two identical substituents (hydrogens)
  on one end of the double bond.
- Double bond "2" is capable of displaying *cis* and *trans* stereoisomers since there are two different substituents on each end of the double bond.
- Double bond "3" can only exist as a *cis* isomer due to the geometric constraints imposed by the 6-membered ring.
- Double bond "4" is a 1,2,3-triene (allene would be a 1,2-diene); such trienes  display the same stereochemical *cis-trans* possibilities as a double bond.
- The substituents on the two cyclohexene carbons contained in circle "5" also have *cis-trans* arrangements; these are further illustrated in the cyclohexene drawings pictured below.
- Finally, each of the carbons contained in circle "5" are chiral (they each have 4 different substituents) and can exist as R and S stereoisomers.

Considering only the circles that can have stereoisomers (2, 4 and 5) we can have the following spatial arrangements:

- 2-*cis*, 4-*cis*, 5-*trans*, and this geometric isomer can further exist as an enantiomeric pair; so 2 stereoisomers in all.
- 2-*trans*, 4-*cis*, 5-*trans*, and this geometric isomer can further exist as an enantiomeric pair; so 2 stereoisomers in all.
- 2-*cis*, 4-*trans*, 5-*trans*, and this geometric isomer can further exist as an enantiomeric pair; so 2 stereoisomers in all.
- 2-*trans*, 4-*trans*, 5-*trans*, and this geometric isomer can further exist as an enantiomeric pair; so 2 stereoisomers in all.
- 2-*cis*, 4-*cis*, 5-*cis*, and this geometric isomer can further exist as an enantiomeric pair; so 2 stereoisomers in all.
- 2-*trans*, 4-*cis*, 5-*cis*, and this geometric isomer can further exist as an enantiomeric pair; so 2 stereoisomers in all.
- 2-*cis*, 4-*trans*, 5-*cis*, and this geometric isomer can further exist as an enantiomeric pair; so 2 stereoisomers in all.
- 2-*trans*, 4-*trans*, 5-*cis*, and this geometric isomer can further exist as an enantiomeric pair; so 2 stereoisomers in all.

Therefore, there are a total of 16 stereoisomers for your molecule, 8 diastereomers, each of which can exist as an enantiomeric pair.

**Thanks to Loong** for pointing out that the *cis* and *trans* geometry in circle "5" limits the R and S possibilities at the two chiral carbon atoms in circle "5".  That is, these carbons in (for example) the *cis* isomer cannot be R,S R,R S,R and S,S, - in the *cis* isomer they can only be either R,S and S,R **or** R,R and S,S.