# How is the central carbon in 3‐bromopentane‐2,4‐diol chiral?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

My teacher told us the middle carbon in 3‐bromopentane‐2,4‐diol is chiral:

$$\ce{CH3-CH(OH)-\overset{\star}{C}H(Br)-CH(OH)-CH3}$$

Since there are two identical groups around it, I would guess it should not be chiral.

It was a pre-recorded class and I was not able ask this question. Has my teacher made a mistake?

Comment: The carbons either side bearing the -OH groups are chiral so are potentially non-identical

Comment: The carbon can only be pseudochiral. Its configuration can matter but in that case, it will sit in the plane of symmetry.

Comment: This issue is addressed here: http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/RSrs.html

Comment: Also see this; https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/91539/mismatch-of-plane-of-symmetry-vs-gold-books-definition-for-a-pseudochiral-carbo/91892#91892

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Carbons #2 and #4 are chiral centres themselves. There are four possible diastereoisomers:

[image: Diastereomers of 3-bromopentane-2,4-diol]

If C2 and C4 have different configurations, which is the case in molecules **A** and **D**, then C3 is termed a [pseudoasymmetric centre](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/35511/16683) and labelled with a small 'r' or 's'. These diastereomers are meso compounds: although they contain chiral centres, they are not chiral, because they have an internal plane of symmetry.

On the other hand, in molecules **B** and **C**, C2 and C4 have the same configuration and C3 is not a chiral centre (and not a pseudoasymmetric centre either). These diastereomers *are* chiral, though: the chirality comes from C2 and C4.

Comment: So it's chiral in some cases and not in others ? Like Zhe said in the comments ?

Comment: Actually, some of the diastereoisomers are chiral molecules, i.e. without internal mirror image or rotational symmetry. I hope this helps.

Comment: Rotational symmetry isn't related to chirality. To be more precise, the lack of improper rotations $S_n$ is associated with chirality; but proper rotations $C_n$ have no relation to chirality. PS sorry about the edits. I need to double check this.

Comment: Think that should be right now..