# Is this formula for number of optical isomers correct?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

For a symmetric molecule with an even number of chiral centres (for acyclic molecules with chiral centres only, not considering $\pi$ bonds or rings), the formulae (also mentioned in [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/57017/108935)) are:

> No. of meso isomers $=2^{\frac n 2 -1}$
>
> No. of optical isomers $=2^{n-1}$

However, when I went to test it out on $\ce{CH3-CHD-CHD-CHD-CHD-CH3}$ ($n=4$), my results were not matching with the formula.

I got $2$ meso isomers:
[image: Meso 1]
[image: Meso 2]

And I got $6$ enantiomer pairs ($12$ optical isomers):
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The formula for meso isomers seems to match; $2^{{4 \over 2} -1} = 2^1 = 2$

But the formula for optical isomers doesn't match; $2^{4-1} = 2^3 = 8 \neq 12$

Where did I go wrong? Or is the formula wrong? If so, what is the correct formula?

Comment: No simple general formula exists, unless you introduce more restrictions than given by the literal interpretation of the sentence "*for a symmetric molecule with an even number of chiral centres*". For one, you can have optical isomers with *no* chiral centers.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Sorry for not mentioning that, this formula is for acyclic molecules with chiral centres only, not considering $\pi$ bonds or rings (basically the simple case)

Comment: I feel that the formulae should satisfy the condition: 
$($No. of meso isomers$)\ \times\ 2\ +\ ($No. of optical isomers$)\ =\ 2^n$.
$$$$
This would give us: No. of optical isomers $= 2^n - 2^{\frac n 2}$,

which matches with the example I took. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the enantiomeric pairs 1 and 4; 2 and 3 are identical. Just rotate the molecule by 180 degrees about an axis perpendicular and passing through the centre of CH3 - CH3 line. This counting problem arises when symmetrical molecule can be numbered from two ends. Hope this helps..

Comment: So just reduce the number of enantiomers you counted by 4 i.e. there are 8 enantiomers and the formula is correct. 
Also when there are odd number of chiral centres (similar to above problem), the total number of stereoisomers = 2^(n-1).

Comment: Why don't you add your comment to own answer?

Answer (score 2):

You disproved the formula for the number of optical isomers. You are better off to count off $2^n$ different combinations of $R/S$ configurations, then note that the mesos are counted twice (because the intended mirror-image pairs are just one isomer for meso compounds).

So the true number of optical isomers is $2^n-2^{(n/2)-1}$, out of which $2^{(n/2)-1}$ are the meso compounds and the rest consist of enatiomeric pairs.

Thus for $n=4$ you have $2^4-2^1=14$ total optical isomers, which matches your two meso compounds and 12 others that are six pairs of enantiomers.

Comment: I detect a down vote, now if I could detect suggestions from the voter for improvement that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these formulas for finding number of stereoisomers for a given compound:

1. **Geometrical Isomers:**

If n is odd: $2^{n-1}+2^{\frac {n+1}{2}-1}$

If n is even: $2^{n-1}+2^{\frac {n}{2}-1}$

2. **Optical Isomers:**

(2.1) *If there is no meso compound:*

Optically Active Isomers(O.A): $2^{n}$

Racemic Mixtures obtained: $\frac {O.A}{2}$

(2.2) *If there is a meso compound:*

(2.2.1) (For even values of n)

Optically Active Isomers: $2^{n-1}$

Meso Isomers: $2^{\frac {n}{2}-1}$

(2.2.2) (For odd values of n)

Optically Active Isomers: $2^{n-1}$

Meso Isomers: $2^{\frac {n-1}{2}}$